# Symfony/Webpack.encore configuration, add "modules rules" for using typescript with vue.js

Tags: typescript, symfony, vue.js, webpack

I'm using Symfony 5 with webpack.encore and vue.js as front-end framework.
I want to use typescript in vue.

This basically works but I get an errer-msg when I try to import components, like this:

**homepage.ts**

```
import Vue1 from "vue";

import App from '../vue/homepage'; 
// Error: TS2307: Cannot find module '../vue/homepage' or its corresponding type declarations

new Vue1({
    el: "#app",
    render: (h) => h(App),       
});
```

**homepage.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <h1>This works</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: "Homepage",
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
    ...
</style>
```

This problem was discussed here: [Stackoverflow/42002394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002394/importing-vue-components-in-typescript-file)

The solution in answer one is to add modules.rules to the webpack.config.js:

**webpack.config.js**

```
{ modules: { rules: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
    loader: "ts-loader",
    options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] }
  },
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      esModule: true
    }
  }
]}}
```

The problem for me is that I don't know how to translate this solution to the webpack.encore syntax which is different from normal webpack.

I found that there is a definition to define loader-rules like this:

```
// Using Encore.configureLoaderRule()
Encore.configureLoaderRule('eslint', loaderRule => {
    loaderRule.test = /\.(jsx?|vue)$/
});
```

but I don't know how translate the solution to this webpack.encore format.

**Edit: add full webpack.config.js**

**webpack.config.js**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')     
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .configureUrlLoader({
        images: {
        esModule: false
    }
    })
    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */     
    .addEntry('homepage', './assets/pages/homepage/ts/homepage.ts')

    .splitEntryChunks()

    .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .enableVueLoader()
 
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets', pattern: /\.svg|.png|.jpg|.tif|.ico$/ ,
        to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    }
    )

    // PostCss Loade enablen
    .enablePostCssLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    .enableTypeScriptLoader()    
    
    .enableForkedTypeScriptTypesChecking() 
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**Edit: add tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions":{
    "experimentalDecorators": true,   

    /* Basic Options */  
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2015",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */


    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
     "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
     "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
     "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
     "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
     "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
     "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
     "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
     "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
     "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
     "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
     "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
     "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */   
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your complete webpack.config.js?

Comment: @Jeroen - I edit the question and add the webpack.config.js

Comment: Thanks, and you got a proper tsconfig.json?

Comment: @Jeroen - add it

Comment: You don't have to use their builder.

Comment: @sitox Can you try it with module: "CommonJS" in your tsconfig?

Comment: @Jeroen: okay I've set the module to commonjs, but it makes no different.

Comment: ok was just a guess, I am using Typescript as well in my current Symfony / Vue project but not sure whats different...