# Import class from vue file in typescript file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue 2 with a TypeScript layer (`vue-property-decorator`).

I have a class called `BaseForm` in a `.vue` file:

```js
<template>
  <div class="base-form">
    <form>
      <slot />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class BaseForm extends Vue {
  comment = '';
}
</script>
```

I want to access the `comment` variable of the `BaseForm` class in a `.ts` file like so:

```js
import BaseForm from '@/components/BaseForm.vue';
setComment(form: BaseForm, comment: string) {
  form.comment = comment;
}
```

But in the `.ts` file the `BaseForm` is not typed as `class` but as (Vue) `interface` and I can not access the variable.

My `shims-vue.d.ts` looks like (I got that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46315677/3459910)):

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue;
}
```

I tried to add something like this (but it did not work):

```
declare module 'BaseForm.vue' {
  import BaseForm from '@/components/base/BaseForm.vue';
  export default BaseForm;
}
```

Any advice how to use a class in a non-vue file?

Comment: Using Vue-observable create a variable inside the component file. You can export it as well use inside the class too. It will be reactive everywhere.

Comment: @FarazShuja I can't access the variable inside the component file from a plain `.ts` file as the plain `.ts` file loads every class as `interface Vue` which in return does not provide such a variable.

Comment: Ah right! Then you need to create either a vuex store or some mini module via Vue.observable and import in component as well as in ur .ts file.